# Wpf Tooltip style on Datagrid rowselected

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have this problem with a tooltip in a datagrid( See picture )[image]
But it's only then the row is selected ( See picture below )[image]

Have can i change the the style in the datagrid to make the the Foreground Black then the row is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the white comes from the same resource as your highlighted first cell, so this will be affected as well.

Try this :

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Orange"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```